# Excel Countif Multiple Criteria based on ID

Tags: excel, countif, multiple-conditions

I am trying to create a formula that will count an ID in one column if it means several criteria in another column. Other formulas I've seen are close to what I want but none consider ID.

My data look like this:

[image]

The formula you see in the formula box is the closest thing I could get but it sums up the number of times it gets all the criteria. 
  My wish list simplified is:

1. to get a 1 in Column G based on ClientEnrollmentID if Column C has
   "Initial" OR "Annual".
2. same as above except "Initial" AND "Annual".

For example, 1074328692 (the first ClientEnrollmentID--H2) should be 1 for the first wish and 0 for the second wish.
1074331324 (second row--H3-H5) should be 1 because it satisfies the two wishes (it would be okay for 1 to appear in multiple rows for the ClientEnrollmentID).

My third wish is that someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just math. Maybe this can help:

1. `=MIN(COUNTIFS(H:H, H:H, C:C, "Initial") + COUNTIFS(H:H, H:H, C:C,"Annual"), 1)`
2. `=COUNTIFS(H:H, H:H, C:C, "Initial") * COUNTIFS(H:H, H:H, C:C, "Annual")`

Comment: Brilliant (even though you say "just math"). This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I also needed "Initial" AND "Annual" OR "Semiannual" and tweaked the formula like this:  =COUNTIFS(H:H,H:H,C:C,"Initial")*MIN(COUNTIFS(H:H,H:H,C:C,"Semiannual")+COUNTIFS(H:H,H:H,C:C,"Annual"),1)    which also worked. Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

A [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) can be given OR criteria in the form of an array of constants if you wrap it in a [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57).

[image: SUM over COUNTIFS]

The formula in G2 is,

[image: SUM over COUNTIFS formula one]

The second wish can be derived as either a 1 or 0 with an AND function.

[image: SUM over COUNTIFS formula two]

If they have to be in one cell, you could concatenate them together with something like a division symbol separating them like this.

[image: SUM over COUNTIFS two]

Of course, that renders them completely ineffective for any totaling or mathematical comparison without parsing the string.